# A Lemma from Freyd

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

This is a lemma from Freyd's *Abelian Categories* stated without proof.

In an abelian category, $$A\rightarrow S \rightarrowtail B = A \rightarrow B$$ if and only if $$A\rightarrow B \twoheadrightarrow \mathrm{coker}(S\rightarrowtail B)=0$$

The proof of the $\Downarrow$ direction is immediate, but I haven't managed to prove the $\Uparrow$ direction. Hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to prove that, given a morphism $f: A\to B$ and a subobject $j: S\rightarrowtail B$ with cokernel $\pi: B\twoheadrightarrow\text{coker}(S\rightarrowtail B)$ (in an abelian category), you have $f$ factoring through $j$ if and only if $\pi\circ f=0$?

For the direction "$\Leftarrow$" note that any monomorphism is the kernel of its cokernel.

You might also want to think of a counterexample in the (non-abelian) category of groups we were discussing yesterday in [Quotient Objects in $\mathsf{Grp}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069005/quotient-objects-in-mathsfgrp/1069044).

Comment: That any monic is the kernel of its cokernel is the content of theorem 2.11 in Freyd. This yields $A \rightarrow B \twoheadrightarrow \mathrm{coker}(\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{coker}(S\rightarrowtail B)))$ but I don't see what do from here :\

Comment: @Exterior: if $\pi\circ f=0$, then the universal property of the kernel of $\pi$ tells you that $f$ factors through $\text{ker}(\pi)\rightarrowtail B$ which can be taken to be $S\rightarrow X$

Comment: So simple, thanks!